# Attempting different command with sudo and without

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, pip

I have recently uninstalled and reinstalled pip. Then when I try executing it I get

```
eli@eli-VirtualBox:/usr/local/bin$ pip --version
bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

But when I try it with `sudo` I get

```
eli@eli-VirtualBox:/usr/local/bin$ sudo pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

Also, which pip gives me `/usr/local/bin/pip`

Why is `sudo` and non `sudo` trying to find pip in different places, and why is it not working without `sudo`, since `/usr/local/lib` is earlier in the `PATH` variable, and pip has `777` permission?
Please enlighten me.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install `pip`? What's the output of `echo "$PATH"` vs. `sudo sh -c 'echo "$PATH"'`? Don't use 777 permissions for no apparent reason! Files in `/usr/local` are typically be owned by `root` and have 0644 with directories and executables in `/usr/local/bin` and sometimes in `/usr/local/lib` having 0755, which leaves them writeable by their owner (typically `root`) and readable and executable/traversable (for executables/directories) by everybody.

Answer (score 3):

Likely you have a broken version of pip (maybe with missing shared libraries) in `/usr/local/bin`.

When you use `sudo`, `/usr/local` isn't searched because it's not in sudo's `secure_path` - so the working version in `/usr/bin` is found instead.